# Como agrupar un DataFrame por intervalos

Tags: python, group-by

Como ejemplo de Dataframe podríamos suponer el siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['tamaño'] = [6,5,4,1,2,3,6,5,4,1,4,5,6,2,3,6,5,4]
df['peso'] = [7,9,4,5,6,9,8,5,2,3,6,1,2,5,4,8,4,8]
```

Mi intención es obtener los datos del DataFrame que cumplen que tienen un tamaño entre los valores 5 y 7 y un peso entre 1 y 5.

AL principio pensé en utiliza la agrupación de datos con bucles for. Algo así

```
grupoTamaño = df.groupby(by=['tamaño']) 
for i in [5,6,7]:
  nuevoDF=grupoTamaño.get_group((i))
     for  in [1,2,3,4,5]
           grupoPeso = nuevoDF.groupby(by=['peso'])
           a=grupoPeso.get_group((j))
           resultado=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([0]),a])
```

Pero me gustaría poder seleccionar un grupo directamente con un intervalo. Algo del estilo:

```
grupo = df.groupby(by=['tamaño','peso']) 
grupo.get_group((5-7,1-5))
```

Y que me obtuviese los grupos en esos rangos

MUCHAS GRACIAS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo más parecido a lo que pides sería lo siguiente:

```
df[df.tamaño.between(5,7) & df.peso.between(1,5)]
```

Que produce la siguiente salida sobre tu dataframe de ejemplo:

```
    tamaño  peso
7        5     5
11       5     1
12       6     2
16       5     4
```

No sé si es algo como esto lo que buscabas o estabas pensando en otra cosa. Tu intento de usar grupos me confunde, ya que en principio no veo que tengan nada qué ver con lo que pretendes. Si no es así, por favor edita la pregunta para aclarar mejor por qué intentas usar grupos.

Comment: Justo eso me soluciona al dedillo lo que andaba buscando! muchisimas gracias